# Contact 7 Special Tag not working on my site?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to know the **Page Title/Slug** from the mails sent out from the **Contact 7** (placed in a sidebar widget) of the Page.

Unfortunately, with the Special Tag `[_url]` included in the Mail section, the mail isn't reaching the Inbox.

However the mail is reaching the inbox when the Special Tag `[_url]` is **excluded** in Mail section ?!

[Contact 7 Special mail-tags][1]

Anyone care to troubleshoot the issue ?

In short, why isn't the **Contact 7 Special Tag** not working on my site ?

Is the issue with the Mail provider or Contact 7 Form or the Wordpress theme ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi.  There is not enough information in your question to even begin to answer.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that.

[Page with Contact 7 form placed on the Right Sidebar](https://www.majestic-printers.com/template/annual-report-template-vol9/)

[`[_url]` placed on the Form section of the Contact 7 Page](https://ibb.co/T4ynjcZ)

[`[_url]` placed on the Mail Section of the Contact 7 Page](https://ibb.co/XjDsVzm)

[Front end screenshot not showing the Page URL ?](https://ibb.co/GFDNvCW)

Hope this helps.